# Would it be possible to remap the Delete key in Nautilus to a custom script instead of gio?

Tags: gnome, btrfs, nautilus, trash, glib

In Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.5, pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key while in Nautilus runs `gio trash`. There has been a [long-standing issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/1885) with the way `gio` handles Trash within subvolumes in the `btrfs` file system. Five years has passed since the initial issue was reported and as of today (2023) it has not yet been resolved.

I am now thinking of just creating my own script to handle Trash. What I needed, though, is for the script to be called each time I press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key while in Nautilus. Which means **remapping the call from `gio` to the custom script.**

Would this be possible? (Hacks welcome )